# Reading text from a text file in mongodb

Tags: mongodb-query

Does mongo shell  commands support to retrieve / search a words from a text file or PDF or Excel files.

All My files all stored in MongoDB (fs.files  /  fs.chunks) and I am referring my files in a main collection using _id with dbref's.
I want to search a few words from a main collection (db.abc) corresponding file.

Example :

{
        "_id" : ObjectId    ("5a0257610f32472c6c5740c0"),

```
    "chunkSize" : 261120,



    "uploadDate" : ISODate    ("2017-11-08T01:01:21.350Z"),



    "length" : 196172,




    "md5" : "a1fec9f5c652c6d844e2bf35bc08eaae",







    "filename" : "test.txt"
```

}

db.abc.insert     ({"_id": "1",

"project": {

"$ref": "fs.files",

"$id": ObjectId("5a0257610f32472c6c5740c0"),

"$db": "dbname"},

"pp": "987-654-222",

"descr": "circuitboard"

}

)

I Want to  search a words from  text.txt at Mongo shell using mongodb commands.

does it possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. It is considered good practice to show what you have tried to tackle a particular problem rather than only asking people to provide a solution. Ideally in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am able to  put/get the files using mongofiles.exe Utility